# How to change webapp folder on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, server

I use tomcat 8.5.31 on Windows Server 2012 r2.

I need to change webapp folder from: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps` to `C:\Alessandrotest\webapps`

I tried to modify in conf/server.xml this parameters:

```
>      <Host name="localhost"
            appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true"
            autoDeploy="true" >
```

In this mode

```
>      <Host name="localhost"
            appBase="/C:/Alessandrotest/webapps"
            unpackWARs="true"
            autoDeploy="true" >
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use below syntax and test.

```
<Host name="localhost"
            appBase="C:/Alessandrotest/webapps"
            unpackWARs="true"
            autoDeploy="true" >
```